Copying a large Excel Range as Picture and getting it to stay resized
So the Problem I have is: an Excel Range copy as picture is not staying larger in the email that sends - like outlook is doing some auto resize while sending. See below code and wondering what I can change or turn off to allow this automation to work
Sub myemailSender()
        'Email Set up
        Email_Subject = "my_subject"
        Email_Send_To = "my_email"
        
        Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
        
        With Mail_Single
         .Subject = Email_Subject
         .To = Email_Send_To
         .Display
        End With
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets("Mysheet").Calculate
        Range("MyCopyRange").Copy
        Range("MyCopyRange").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        
        Const wdInlineShapePicture = 3
        Set wrdDoc = Mail_Single.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wrdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
        For Each wrdShp In wrdDoc.InlineShapes
            If wrdShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
                ' Increase the scale to make the image larger
                wrdShp.ScaleHeight = 150 ' Adjust this value as needed
                wrdShp.ScaleWidth = 150  ' Adjust this value as needed
            End If
        Next
        Mail_Single.Send
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub



Rename the Word document as .zip and then open it as a zip file (or save to HTML format). That will allow you to see what is really in the file. MS Word and Excel are devils for scaling large images to fit A4 or US paper sizes on the fly. If you are lucky the data is all there just scaled in an unfortunate way that renders it illegible.

what line would that go in the code on?

It doesn't go anywhere. Take the .DOC  file that your code has saved and examine it using either of the methods that let you see what is actually inside the ".DOC" which is in reality a mis-named .zip file. Open .DOC save as HTML does it from inside word, the rename trick allows you to see the entire DOC structure and all its embedded images.

ok and similar applies to an excel file which is what this comes out of as a named range

How large is the range you're copying?

75 by 18 inch is what it shows
